# What would be a fast way to size-promote an array of unsigned integral elements?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, type-conversion, type-erasure

I need to implement the function:

```
promote(
    unsigned char*   __restrict__  dest, 
    unsigned char*   __restrict__  src 
    size_t                         src_element_size, 
    size_t                         dest_element_size, 
    size_t                         n
);
```

which takes an array of n (unsigned) integers, each of which represented by `src_element_size` consecutive bytes, and writes as output an array of n integers each represented by another number of bytes, `dest_element_size`. Let's assume dest_element_size > src_element_size, and that both arrays are aligned appropriately for their own type.

What would be a fast/the fastest way to perform this conversion?

**Notes:**

- This is *not* a `memcpy()`, nor `memset()` + `memcpy()`. For example, If the source element size is 1 and the target element size is 2, and the source bytes are `123, 123, 123` then the destination bytes are `123, 0, 123, 0, 123, 0`. You could think of it as a "strided `memcpy()`" I suppose.
- The endianness is either the machine endianness or little-endianness, whichever you wish to assume.
- `src_element_size` and `dest_element_size` are typically small and power-of-two (1,2,4,8) - but I'd rather get answers which are relevant to somewhat larger sizes (say < 200), and also for non-power-of-two sizes (3, 6 etc.)
- The function itself may not be templated, but a suggestion for templating the implementation would be valid. The reason is that this will sit in a compiled library and code using it will not be recompiled with the template definition/header with __Generic.
- No multi-threading / GPUs/ Xeon Phis/ or other exotic hardwaree.
- `src_element_size` is less-than-or-equal-to `dest_element_size`.

Comment: Side note, but I think all size parameters here should be `size_t`.

Comment: @StoryTeller: Done.

Comment: You want to implement memcpy but with an obscure function prototype? Why can't you use memcpy? What does "size promote" mean?

Comment: @Lundin: It's not memcpy. If the source element size is 1 and the target element size is 2, and the source bytes are 123, 123, 123 then the destination bytes are 123, 0, 123, 0, 123, 0. I'll make that clearer.

Comment: So it is memset zero plus memcpy, in a loop. Btw it is quite pointless to tag this as both C and C++, since solutions will be quite different. Can you change the prototype? In C you would then use _Generic, in C++ you would use templates.

Comment: @Lundin: No, that's not it. A memset-0 and a memcpy would not produce the result in the example I gave. Also, I constrained non-genericity.

Comment: So, if I'm getting you you are trying to code a _copy n byte from src and put them into dest every n bytes_. What is `n` used for?

Comment: you are asking for a "fast way", do you have already have an implementation as well as a benchmark? you should post that here.

Comment: I'm not an expert on the matter, but `restrict` qualified pointers might aid compiler in better optimization.

Comment: What if `src_element_size` is bigger than `dest_element_size`?

Comment: @SimonKraemer: Implicitly assumed not to happen, will clarify that point.

Answer (score 4):

If you can't use C `_Generic` or C++ templates, then you have to use a memset zero + memcpy.

```
memset(dest, 0, n);
for(size_t i=0; i<n; i++)
{
  memcpy(dest, src, src_size);
  dest += dest_size;
  src  += src_size;
}
```

The result will be "left-aligned", so this will only work for little endian.

An endianess-independent version will be a bit more intricate. You would have to replace memcpy with a loop, which bit shifts the individual bytes in place.

Or possibly something like this:

```
const uint16_t endian=1;
const bool is_little_endian = *(const uint8_t*)&endian == 1;
size_t offset = is_little_endian ? 0 : dest_size-src_size;

memset(dest, 0, n);
for(size_t i=0; i<n; i++)
{
  memcpy(dest + offset, src, src_size);
  dest += dest_size;
  src  += src_size;
}
```

As someone pointed out a comment, you should declare both character pointers as `restrict` to tell the compiler that it can assume they aren't pointing at the same location, for a bit of micro-optimization.

---

A solution with `_Generic` might look something like (not tested):

```
#define promote(dst, src, n)                                              \
  _Generic((dst),                                                         \
           unsigned char*:                                                \
             _Generic((src),                                              \
               unsigned char*:  promote_uchar_uchar,                      \
             ),                                                           \
                                                                          \
           unsigned int*:                                                 \
             _Generic((src),                                              \
                      unsigned char*: promote_uint_uchar,                 \
                      unsigned int*:  promote_uint_uint                   \
             ),                                                           \
           )(dst, src, n)                                                 

inline void promote_uchar_uchar (unsigned char* dest, unsigned char* src, size_t n)
{
  for(size_t i=0; i<n; i++)
  {
    dest[i] = src[i];
  }
}

inline void promote_uint_uchar (unsigned int* dest, unsigned char* src, size_t n)
{
  for(size_t i=0; i<n; i++)
  {
    dest[i] = src[i];
  }
}
```

Better yet, you can adjust this to for even better type safety:

```
inline void promote_uint_uchar (size_t n, unsigned int[static n], unsigned char[static n])
```

Comment: Maybe you want to introduce a check for ensuring that `src_size`  is smaller than `dst_size` - Otherwise this will produce undefined behaviour.

Comment: So, you're suggesting a I make a function call for each element? That does not sound like a great idea.

Comment: @SimonKraemer Or just document that it should be smaller.

Comment: @einpoklum Why not? It will be much faster and much safer than the first, generic version. I would suspect that the plain for loops give much better cache performance and also less instructions overall.

Comment: @Lundin: Build a stack frame, do the small for loop, pop SP and IP - for a single element, which might be 1-2 bytes?